# Issue with Rendering Component Presentations in TridionHelper.cs

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, dd4t, dd4t-2

We are working on DD4T 2.0 with Tridion 2013SP1. Below is the error we are facing.

The actual issue is that when the solution is build for first time, There is NO error and we get our normal page displayed. However, as soon as we recycle App Pool and reload the same page, this error appears.

As seen in stack trace, I checked the `TridionHelper.cs` file and so far, I verified the `Appsettings` Key for DD4T and verified the Log4net settings as well, but it didn't help.

It Seems an issue with Log4net as we observed that nothing is written to the Log files.

Any further steps to help resolve this issue ?

[image]